# How do I update a variable from a string in vue?

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, vuejs3

I have a function that gets a string which contains a variable name, the function should set that variable to false after a 1 second delay and only if another specific variable is false, but I cant figure out how to be able to change the variable via the given string. It is a Nuxt 3 project.

The function:

```
mouseLeaveMenu(btn){
    setTimeout(() => {
        if (this.mouseOverMenu == false){
            this.btn = false
        }
    }, 1000);
```

How I call it

```
<div @mouseleave="mouseLeaveMenu('productsHover')">
... stuff here
</div>
```

It should change the variable productsHover to false then, is there a solution that doesnt require me to write an if for each of the variables that it should possibly change?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a data object in your Vue component to store the variables you want to control:

```
data() {
  return {
    variables: {
      productsHover: false,
      // Add other variables here as needed
    },
    mouseOverMenu: false,
  };
},
```

Update your mouseLeaveMenu function to use the object to set the variable to false after a 1-second delay:

```
mouseLeaveMenu(variableName) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    if (!this.mouseOverMenu && this.variables.hasOwnProperty(variableName)) {
      this.variables[variableName] = false;
    }
  }, 1000);
},
```

Now, when you call mouseLeaveMenu('productsHover'), it will set this.variables.productsHover to false after a 1-second delay, but only if this.mouseOverMenu is also false.

Make sure to replace 'productsHover' with the actual variable names you want to control in your component. This way, you don't need to write an if statement for each variable you want to handle; the function will work with any variable name you pass as an argument.